# Update query in a PHP page is not updating multiple rows, even if no error message is recieved

Tags: php, oracle11g

I am updating two tables using a PHP page. first table has a single row to update and second table has multiple rows to be updated on where clause. The problem is first table is being successfully updated but second table is not getting updated. though no error is being recieved. The variables in set and where clause in statement are passed on from previous page. I have used echo at various places to check whether the values are passed correctly. Even though everything looks fine, th code is not working.

```
   <?php
 include 'Millsdbconnection_test.php';
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
 session_start();
$var_value = $_POST['dsg'];
$var_value1 = $_SESSION['Heat'];
echo $var_value;
echo $var_value1;
insert_billet($var_value,$var_value1);
function insert_billet($dsg,$HeatId){
include 'Millsdbconnection_test.php';
$dsg2=$dsg;
$HeatId2=$HeatId;
$sql = 'update stg_bil_layer set STEEL_GRADE_ID= :xx where heat_id= :yy';
$query = oci_parse($c,$sql);            
oci_bind_by_name($query, ':xx', $dsg);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ':yy', $HeatId);
            oci_execute($query);
            if (!oci_execute($query) ){
                $errd=oci_error($query);
                trigger_error('Query failed: ' 
      .$errd['message'],E_USER_ERROR);
            }       

                echo 'Here';
                echo $dsg2;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $HeatId2;
                $sql2 = 'update stg_billet set STEEL_GRADE_ID=:aa where 
    heat_id=:bb';
                $query2= oci_parse($c,$sql2);
                oci_bind_by_name($query2, ':aa', $dsg2);
                oci_bind_by_name($query2, ':bb', $HeatId2);
                oci_execute($query2);

                if (!oci_execute($query2) ){
                    $errd=oci_error($query2);
                    trigger_error('Query failed: ' 
      .$errd['message'],E_USER_ERROR);
                }else{
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                window.onload = function () { alert('Steel Grade Updated 
      !!!!'); }
                    </script>";
                    //echo $count;
                }


 }

 ?>
```

Comment: which error occurs right now? please upload with screenshot of error.

Comment: I have posted my code. Actually there is no error just the second update query is not giving any results.

Comment: @ravipandey First issue is that you are executing every query twice. When you check ```if (!oci_execute($query) )``` you are executing the query the same as in the line before. I would remove the call prior for both the first and second queries.

Comment: But this has always worked for me and in any case the first query is successfully updating the first table, the problem is only with second query.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the "**safe updates**" option enable on your database. This prevents row updates without a specified primary key.

In MySQL and Oracle (and maybe more), this can be disabled with: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Comment: I'm sorry i have not added my code earlier. you can see there are two update queries. the first one is successfully executing while second one is not.